# WordPress create category for pages only

Tags: wordpress, categories, custom-wordpress-pages

I need to assign category for pages,i have tried many of the results found in google search . But while adding a category for Pages it automatically reflects in Posts also. Also tried few plugins (https://wordpress.org/plugins/create-and-assign-categories-for-pages/) . Is there an option for adding categories for pages alone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom module instead ? with page capabilities and put supports "page_attributes"

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose to divide the pages? If you want to relate a group of pages create a parent page and use that! it can be used like a category.